# Understanding of .then() behaviour in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop, axios

Please correct me if I am wrong.

As per my understanding **.then()** will only execute once the dependent function finishes its task.
However here I could see different order of execution.

Suppose array size is 20, console.log(i) (inside axios) prints in different order like 18, 12, 11,3,15 ... so on. using **.then()** can't we make it synchronous?.

I know adding *await* keyword in front of *Axios* would work perfectly. But, just to make sure, is there any other way to achieve it?.

**Observed Behaviour.**

1. When we execute this without await, this would work for few array items (it will be very fast).
2. When we execute using await keyword it will take too much time.

```
var pdflist = ['one','two','three','four'.........'twenty']
for (let i=0; i<pdflist.length;i++)
{
            let uri = {
              method: 'GET',
              url:'https://pdffiles/'+pdflist[i]+'.pdf',
              responseType: "arraybuffer"
            };

            axios(uri).then(results => {
            console.log(i)                // prints in different order
            console.log(results)
            })
}
```

Comment: No, `.then()` does not make an asynchronous operation synchronous. The operations complete when they complete.

Comment: Those requests will run in parallel, they won't wait  to move to the next loop iteration.

Comment: I don’t have time to write an answer right now but `Promise.all` is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: You essentially want to look at this question, even though it uses `forEach` instead of a loop. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/691711

Comment: you can use `async` and `await` to do it in a simple and easy way. `.then()` dosent make an async operation synchronous but you can achieve this kind of behaviour with async and await. Although it internally uses `promise` to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can solve the this issue with `async` and `await`.

```
const fn = async () => {
    var pdflist = ['one','two','three','four'.........'twenty']
    for (let i=0; i<pdflist.length;i++)
    {
        let uri = {
          method: 'GET',
          url:'https://pdffiles/'+pdflist[i]+'.pdf',
          responseType: "arraybuffer"
        };

        const result = await axios(uri)
        console.log(i)                // prints in different order
        console.log(results);
    }
}
fn()
```

Using `Promise.all`

```
var pdflist = ['one','two','three','four'.........'twenty']
var promises = [];
for (let i=0; i<pdflist.length;i++)
{
    let uri = {
      method: 'GET',
      url:'https://pdffiles/'+pdflist[i]+'.pdf',
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
    };

    promises.push(axios(uri))
}

Promise.all(promises).then((allResults) => {
    allResults.forEach((res, i) => {
        console.log(i)                // prints in different order
        console.log(res);
    })
})
```

Comment: No need to do `return Promise.resolve()` in async functions. Just `return;` would do, and since it's the final statement of the function, you could just elide it.

Comment: @Punith Mithra, thank you, I got understood well.

Comment: @Punith This fails when we get a single error.